# Spring Boot - OpenAPI - Tell API to use certain subclass for example

Tags: java, spring-boot, springdoc-openapi-ui

I have an class hierarchy as below

```
public class Car {
     private String make; 
     private String model; 
     
     @Schema(example = "MANUAL")
     private TransmissionType transmissionType;

     @JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXTERNAL_PROPERTY, 
          property = "transmissionType")
     private Transmission transmission; 
}

@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = AutomaticTransmission.class, name = "AUTOMATIC"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = ManualTransmission.class, name = "MANUAL"))
})
public abstract class Transmission {
}

public class AutomaticTransmission {
     @Schema(example = "DCT")
     public Technology technology;
}

public class ManualTransmission {
     @Schema(example = "5")
     public int numGears; 
}
```

Now, when swagger is generated, I see that for car model,

```
{
   "transmissionType": "MANUAL"
   "transmission": {  
       "technology": "DCT"
   }
}
```

Here transmission type is manual but example given of automatic. Requirement is give example of manual transmission. How do I link these two properties.

I know that I can create an example json and put it in `@Schema(example = "{\"numGears\": 5}")` but this will create maintenance overhead of modifying json when class is modified.

Comment: Have you tried defining also a `@Schema` for field transmission?